# R - calculate the prediction interval with glmmTMB

Tags: r, statistics, mixed-models, glmmtmb

I'm just looking for the code to calculate the prediction interval (rather than the 95% confidence interval) for my GLMMS. Is that possible using glmmTMB?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Alex,  I am looking to compute also predictions intervals after fitting with glmmTMB package. Have you maybe found a solution?